# Cannot debug app on Android 4.1 on device

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, adb, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 11 on MacOS 10.7 to develop and Galaxy Nexus device for testing. The app is targeting Android 2.3.

Recently I've updated to JellyBean (4.1.1) on the Galaxy Nexus (official update from Google, not rooted/otherwise). Since then I cannot properly debug the app anymore in Idea11. The device is visible in LogCat but the output has changed: no logs, no messages, no exceptions... 
All I'm getting is something like:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 209K, 5% free 11729K/12295K, paused 11ms+12ms, total 44ms
[ 07-23 18:24:34.180  4425: 4425 D/dalvikvm ]
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 53K, 3% free 10956K/11271K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
[ 07-23 18:24:34.180  4425: 4425 I/dalvikvm-heap ]
Grow heap (frag case) to 12.194MB for 1536016-byte allocation
[ 07-23 18:24:34.219  4425: 4429 D/dalvikvm ]
GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 12454K/12807K, paused 13ms+1ms, total 34ms
[ 07-23 18:24:34.274  4425: 4425 D/dalvikvm ]
```

I've enabled debugging on the phone, "Unknown sources", selected the app as the debug app. Also, when enabling "Wait for debugger to attach" the application waits forever. Somehow the debugger fails to attach... I can't figure out what the problem is. When attaching a device with Android 2.3 the debug works as expected. I assume it's an issue with the most recent Android update. I've updated to the latest everything in the SDK manager.

Any help in solving this issue is welcome. :)

Comment: Update to IDEA 11.1.3 or IDEA 12 EAP for proper 4.1.1 support: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP.

Comment: IDEA is 11.0. I will update and come back on the topic. Thanks!

Comment: Updated to 11.1.3 EAP, seems to work fine for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems seems to be with IDEA 11. Upgrading to IDEA 11.1.3 seems to have done the trick. It now works as expected (for now). Thanks to CrazyCoder for the helpful comment above. :)